# Is there any programming system that enables reversible computations?

Tags: computability, programming-languages, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Better explained with examples, I need a programming system with the following characteristics:

```
f = λ a b c -> a + b + c
g = apply f 1 2 3 = 6
h = unapply g _ 2 _ = λ b -> 4 + b
```

Or, to explain with words, `f` is a function, `g` is that function applied to 3 arguments, and `h` is `g` "unapplied" to one argument. That is, I need a programming system where you can define functions and apply them to arguments, like the Lambda Calculus. But I also need this system to have an `unapply` operator, with which you can recover a partially applied function from the value of its argument.

Comment: What is `unapply g _ 3 _` ? Anyway, since `g` is clearly not a numeric type, it might as well be a tuple of `f` and `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Nothing, maybe `unapply g _ * _` would be better. I just wanted to empathise the information preservation. Also, yes, but that approach means you have to re-apply "g" to the other arguments. I was thinking some system more natural / two-ways could exist.

Comment: It does seem that partially reappplying seems easier to do than unapplying, as not all functions are inversible.

Comment: why do you need this? a general principle that commands propagate their arguments forward as well as their computation works for reversibility. in qm computing this is called [ancilla bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancilla_(quantum_computing)). another option is reversible logic gates. also note the functions/data cannot be mutable (store state).